# How to plot a spectrum using JFreeChart without wide histogram bins?

Tags: java, user-interface, plot, histogram, jfreechart

I am using `JFreeChart`Java library to display my data. I basically want to represent a mass spectrum (m/z and intensity) in the form of a `plot`. I am using the following code, which used the `createHistogram` method to generate the plot:

```
spectrumPlot = ChartFactory.createHistogram(node.toString(),
                "m/z", "Intensity", dataset1, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, false, false, false);
```

I get the correct plot, but when I zoom-in the width of the histogram bars also increases. And, due to this, the bars appear to be spanning a specific width (whereas it should be a single 1 point line). This is how the plot looks at the moment:

[image]

And, I want it to look something like this:

[image]

So, just single vertical bars even if the plot is zoomed. How can I do this?

Comment: Have you looked at `SimpleHistogramBin`?

Comment: @CatalinaIsland So, while using `SimpleHistogramBin`, should I use the bin as zero, because I don't want binning to be done on the dataset. Something like `SimpleHistogramBin(0,0)`

Comment: Cross-posted [here](http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=117605).